# JSP pages are viewed on localhost. But Servelets setup issues. (No backend code works)

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat

I'm very new to this setup. I used to work on PHP which is completely different(I have no idea how to setup using xml).

> I've installed Tomcat.
>
> I have .war files of the project and have pasted them into `tomact7/webapps/`.
>
> I can view my page on browser at `localhost:8080/name_of_war_file`

So, the `.jsp` pages are viewed without any hassle. Whereas the servelets programs are not being executed(probably haven't setup). 
For example: There is form action in a jsp page but it's not being called.

> Folder structure inside tomcat7/webapps:
>
> [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFf1g.png) (inside WEB-INF/classes/com/voting/dao,servelet,update, etc has few `.class` files)

Please note `.class` files are there and not `.java`

Following is the contents of web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>VotingBallot</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
    <param-name>proof-upload</param-name>
    <param-value>C:\tmp\</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Reg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Reg</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Reg2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.Register2Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Reg2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.Login2Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>electionList</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.ElectionListServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>electionList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/electionList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>votenow</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.VoteNowServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>votenow</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/votenow</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>vote</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.VoteServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vote</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/vote</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resultList</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.ResultListServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resultList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resultList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>results</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.voting.servlet.ResultsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>results</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/results</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Also, in addition to this in webapps/ROOT/META-INF there is context.xml

```
<Context path="/" 
antiResourceLocking="false" >


    <Resource name="jdbc/voterdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="arun" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/VotingBallot/"/>
</Context>
```

I have Java EE Eclipse, tomcat7, phpmyadmin as DB viewer and able to view the jsp pages.

I hope I could get some help. And I'm sorry if i was wrong at any place. Any more details, i'm ready to give.

EDIT:
This is the form action snippet:

```
    <%
        String res = request.getParameter("res");
        if (res != null && res.equals("fail")) {
    %>
    <h3>Something went wrong. Please try again later.</h3>
    <%
        } else if (res != null && res.equals("new")) {
    %>
    <h3>EC Admin haven't approved your application yet. You will
        not be able to access this portal by this time.</h3>
    <%
        } else if (res != null && res.equals("rejected")) {
    %>
    <h3>Your application has been disabled by EC Admin. You will
        not be able to access this portal anymore.</h3>
    <%
        } else if (res != null && res.equals("approved")) {
    %>
    <h3>
        You have already been registered and your application is approved.
        You can login <a href='login.jsp'>here</a>.
    </h3>
    <%
        }
    %>
    <header>
        <h2>Voter Registration Form</h2>
        <p>All the fields are mandatory. .</p>
    </header>
    <form action='register' method=post id='reg'>
        <label> Enter your email: </label> <input type=text name='email' /><br>

        <label>Enter password:</label> <input type=password name='pw' /> <br>

        <label>Enter First name: </label> <input type=text name='fn' /><br>

        <label>Enter Last name:</label> <input type=text name='ln' /> <br>
        <label>Select Gender:</label> <select name='gen'>
            <option value='Male'>Male</option>
            <option value='Female'>Female</option>
        </select> <br> <br> <label>Enter Date of Birth</label> <input
            type=date name='dob' /> <br> <br> <label>Enter
            Mobile number</label> <input type=text name='mobile' /> <br> <label>
            Chose your assembly </label> <select name='assembly'>
            <option value="Mysore">Mysore</option>
            <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
            <option value="Hassan">Hassan</option>
        </select> <br> <br> <input type=submit value='PROCEED >>' /> <br>
        <br>
    </form>
```

Comment: what does "not executed" mean? do you see any exceptions on web-page or response like `404`? any exceptions in tomcat logs? also show a sample html <form> with the `action=""` value entered

Comment: Thanks for the reply, see the edit, I've added the form.

Comment: what happens if you try like this `form action='/register'...>` ?

Comment: it says error 404 /register not found. but if its 'register' i get this URL - http://localhost:8080/VotingBallot/register.jsp?res=fail. And those files are .class those are not problem? Sorry I don get this, :(